# Where can I find Ivy default setting values?

Tags: ivy

I looked into my computer and Ivy manual, but I just can not find those default setting values. Sometimes I really need to check if the default values fit my needs and make adjusts accordingly.

E.g. I want to find out the value of `${ivy.ibiblio.default.artifact.pattern}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the default values on each element of the ivysettings, you should find them in the documentation.
See for instance: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/settings.html

If you want to know what is the default ivysettings.xml file, you can find the version in your ivy.jar. Here is the path in the sources of Ivy: [ivysettings.xml](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/ivy/core/trunk/src/java/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml)

Then they are the default properties. Idem, in your classpath or in the sources of Ivy: [ivy.properties](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/ivy/core/trunk/src/java/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivy.properties) and [repository.properties](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/ivy/core/trunk/src/java/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/repository.properties)

Comment: yes, I want the default values on each element of the ivysettings. the 1st link only gives the descriptions of these values, not the exact value.

Comment: Yes it does, look at the last column. For instance: `No, defaults to .ivy2/cache in user home`

Comment: yes thanks. Unfortunately, it does not have the value I am trying to look up `${ivy.ibiblio.default.artifact.pattern}`.

Comment: answer edited with the link to the repository.properties which contains the searched values.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded apache-ivy-2.3.0-src.zip and searched there.
The default value appears to be in ./src/java/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/repository.properties

The value is

```
ivy.ibiblio.default.artifact.pattern = [module]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
```